# Is it possible to call an html file using the .insertBefore() or .insertAfter() methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to be able to call large amounts of html code, but I don't want to have to reformat it into js format. Would it be possible to call an html document instead?

Something like

```
$(HTML DOCUMENT).insertBefore('div');
```

...?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.get` on an HTML file.

```
$.get('file.html', function(html){
  $(html).insertBefore('.some-div');
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Do you know how the html document should be formatted before it's called? Would you treat it the same as any other document and include the <!DOCTYPE html><html>...</html> stuff?

Comment: It can just be a partial HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to jQuery `append` method  https://api.jquery.com/append/.

Something like

```
   $.get('otherHtml.html', function(data){
      $(data).append('body');
   }
```